# Regex to extract values from look behind groups along with subsequent repetitions

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

In a JAVA program, I need to match a text input with a regular expression pattern. Simplistically, the text input looks like this: `"100|200|123,124,125"`.

The output from the above match should find three matches, where all matches will return the two fixed subgroups - `100` and `200` and the variable repeating sub-group `123/124/125`.

Match 1 - `123`
Match 2 - `124`
Match 3 - `125`.
Each of these match output should also include `100` and `200` in two separate groups.

So basically, matches will target extracting patterns such as `'100|200|123'`, `'100|200|124'`, `'100|200|125'`.

I have used this regex: `(?<=(?:(?<first>\d+)\|(?<second>\d+)\|)|,)(?<vardata>\d+)(?=,|$)`.
But I get this error: `+ A quantifier inside a look-behind makes it non-fixed width`

Comment: Why not `"^(?<first>\\d+)\\|(?<second>\\d+)\\|(?<vardata>\\d+(?:/\\d+)*)$"`?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew When I ran the regex on regex101.com, it did not match.

Comment: @anubhava I cannot split on '|' because that will require two separate ooperations - one split and then pattern match, I can only afford single apply match operation here (which includes matcher find and get group operations).

Comment: @AmitGoenka See https://regex101.com/r/MCcuVz/1, I used `/` instead of `,` in my regex above. Your question is not clear. Please add details about what you are doing. Why do you say `.split` will require matching after? What is the final result? Do you have access to Java code?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew the issue with this is that the group vardata returns a comma separated string of '123,124,125' whereas I need those three comma separated values to be individual matches. So my expected output is 3 matches where each match has three groups. Match 1 - 123, Match 2 - 124, Match 3 - 125. Each of these match output should also include 100 and 200. So basically, I need matches like '100|200|123', '100|200|124', '100|200|125'.

Comment: Add all the details to the **question body**, do not leave them in comments, no one pays attention to comments later.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thank you, updated the question

Comment: Ok, I see and that makes perfect sense now why you used capturing groups in a lookbehind. However, you cannot use `+` in lookbehinds pattern since the pattern length is not known to the regex engine.

Comment: See if this works for you: https://regex101.com/r/DfL2Yp/1 You will get comma separated numbers in `group(3)` in a loop while `group(1)` and `group(2)` will give you first 2 numbers.

Comment: Regex alone cannot do the job; you need some app code too. I would follow @anubhava’s suggestion.

Comment: @anubhava Although https://regex101.com/r/DfL2Yp/1 did not exactly return the output I originally expected, but it addresses my problem (because I can just look for group 1 and group 2 occurrences when they exist which suffices for me) and I can work with it in my program. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in comments above, you cannot use variable length assertions in lookbehind in Java regex.

However you can use this regex based on `\G`:

```
(?:(\d+)\|(\d+)\||(?<!^)\G,)(\d+)
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/DfL2Yp/1)

**RegEx Details:**

- `\G` asserts position at the end of the previous match or the start of the string for the first match.
- You will get comma separated numbers in `group(3)` in a loop while `group(1)` and `group(2)` will give you first 2 numbers from input string.